# Sveltekit cannot render pages with actions, but also crashes if prerender is set to false (when deployed to Vercel)

Tags: sveltekit

Feeling pretty stuck, and hopefully I'm just missing something obvious. Fairly sure I am, as I doubt it's a real Sveltekit problem.

I have an app, where in `+layout.ts` I have set `prerender = true`.  I also have a page with actions (`+page.server.ts`).  I cannot get `npm run build` to succeed, *unless* I set `prerender = false` in that page.

However, while setting `prerender = false` is fine for me, it doesn't seem to work when deployed to Vercel. The page with `prerender = false` crashes with a 500 "this serverless function crashed" every time.

So it seems like I'm just stuck. Can't use `prerender = true` because `npm run build` will fail.  Can't use `prerender = false` because then the app with crash when deployed to Vercel.

The `+page.server.ts` with actions has a default action that pulls some data from a DB,and is invoked from a form on the corresponding `.svelte` page whose `method="post"`

Not really sure how to get past this.  Can't easily debug b/c locally in dev mode, everything works just fine.

EDIT: If it helps, the Vercel logs are showing this `2023-02-22T17:59:05.707Z   3cdf5755-5eac-420c-9263-70c4667501a5    ERROR   Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@sveltejs/kit'`